# How to stub function parameter using mockito in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following code which uses cake pattern.

```
trait CropRepositoryComponent {
   val cropRepository:CropRepository = new CropRepository

   class CropRepository extends DBAccess{
        def getAll(f:Crops.type => Column[Boolean],pageNum:Int = 1,noOfRows:Int = 10):Either[String,List[Crop]] ={
            database withSession {
               ... 
            }
        }
        def getFirst(f:Crops.type => Column[Boolean]):Either[String,Crop] = {
            database withSession {
                ....
            }
        }
   }
}
```

and the related test spec

```
class CropRepositorySpec extends Specification with CropRepositoryComponent{
"CorpRepository #getAll " should {
    "return all active crops " in {
        val crops = cropRepository.getAll(?,anyInt(),anyInt()) //How to stub the first parameter using mockito matchers?

    }
}
```

}

How do i stub the first parameter to the method getAll using mockito matchers?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to use `anyObject` - matcher to match function parameters.

So in your case it would be something along these lines:

```
class CropRepositorySpec extends Specification with CropRepositoryComponent{
"CropRepository #getAll " should {
    "return all active crops " in {
        val crops = cropRepository.getAll(anyObject(),anyInt(),anyInt()) //How to stub the first parameter using mockito matchers?
    }
}
```

Comment: using anyObject seems to cause a lot of ambiguity for me: ambiguous implicit values: both method forNothing in object Tuple of type [A]⇒ akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.Tuple[Nothing] and method forUnit in object Tuple of type [A]⇒ akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.Tuple[Unit] match expected type akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.Tuple[R]

Comment: is there a more focused matcher than anyObject that can differentiate functions from something like "Unit"?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a matcher as well,

```
eq("How to stub this parameter using mockito ?")
```

Take a look at the `Matchers` documentation [here](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html):

> Warning:
>
> If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>
> E.g: (example shows verification but the same applies to stubbing):
>
> verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), eq("third argument"));
>     //above is correct - eq() is also an argument matcher
>
> verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), "third argument");
>     //above is incorrect - exception will be thrown because third argument is given without argument matcher.

Comment: I think I had not framed the question correctly. I have edited the question for more clarity. What I am looking for is a way to stub the first parameter in the getAll method which takes a function as a parameter.